# How to get spring RestTemplate, scala and jackson to play nice to together

Tags: json, spring, scala, jackson

I seem to be able to use Jackson to make a mapper of Json-String --> scala.collection.Map.

How can I hook up that same mapper to a RestTemplate?

```
val restTemplate = new RestTemplate()    

val module = new OptionModule with MapModule with SeqModule with IteratorModule
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(module)

// Get some example JSON
val uri = "http://...."
val response:String = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, classOf[String] )

// *** success ***
// Use the mapper directly: String --> scala.collection.Map
val map1 = mapper.readValue(response, classOf[scala.collection.Map[String, Any]])


// Try hooking up the same module to the RestTemplate:   
val wrappingConverter = new WrappingHttpMessageConverter() 
wrappingConverter.getObjectMapper().registerModule(module)
val list = restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
list.add(wrappingConverter)
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(list)

// *** FAILS ***
// org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read    
// JSON: Can not construct instance of scala.collection.Map, problem: abstract types 
// either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be 
// instantiated with additional type information
val map2 = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, classOf[scala.collection.Map[String, Any]] )
```

Comment: 1. What is `WrappingHttpMessageConverter`? I don't see that in the Spring documentation?
2. Probably best, for the purposes of the test, to have separate instance of your module for your separate `ObjectMappers`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Assumtions

1. `WrappingHttpMessageConverter` is a derived class of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, or some class that works like it.
2. You're using Spring 4.0 (though this answer is probably also true for Spring 3.2)

## The problem

The default `RestTemplate` constructor tries to detect if Jackson is on your classpath, and if it is, adds `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to the `MessageConverters` list. Since it's already on the list, it's going to be used before your `WrappingHttpMessageConverter` is ever checked.

That default converter doesn't have the Scala module installed. Here's where things get tricky. `HttpMessageConverterExtractor` *tries* to ask if the first converter can deserialize the type; currently ObjectMapper returns `true` for this test (whether it *should* is a much longer topic, not as clear cut as it might seem). The extractor doesn't handle the idea that one converter could fail, but a later one might succeed (as it would in your case).

## Workarounds

You need to make sure that Spring finds an ObjectMapper configured with the Scala module before it tries with any other. You can do this in a number of ways; the most robust is to search the preconfigured converters and update the first you find, adding a new one if you don't find any:

```
val jacksonConverter = list.asScala.collectFirst {
  case p: MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter => p
}
if (jacksonConverter.isDefined) {
  jacksonConverter.get.getObjectMapper.registerModule(module)
}
else {
  list.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) // or your derived class if you prefer
}
```

Other options include adding your custom message converter to the front of the list, or removing the existing Jackson converter before adding your own.